# image not uploading to mySql via Php

Tags: php, html, mysql, apache, xampp

This function, seems pretty standard, I am not really getting an active button that uploads to the list in my database?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //THis is how you upload a picture to a website
    $file = $_FILES['file'];
    print_r($file);

    $fileName = $_FILES['file']['name'];
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['file']['size'];
    $fileError = $_FILES['file']['error'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['file']['type'];

    $fileExt = explode('.', $fileName);
    $fileActualExt = strtolower(end($fileExt));

    //array for
    $allowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'pdf');

    if(in_array($fileActualExt, $allowed)){
        if($fileError === 0) {
            if($fileSize < 1000000) {
                $fileNameNew = uniqid ('',true). ".". $fileActualExt;
                $fileDestination = '_uploads/'. $fileNameNew;
                move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName);
                header("Location: index.php");
                echo "success";
            }else{echo "Your file is too big hoe";}
        }
        else{echo "good try, youll have to upload again";}
    }
    else{echo "You cannot upload file of this type";}
}

echo $_POST['value'];
//if $_POST == "yes"

$encodedStr = base64_encode('yes.txt'); //may need to encode inside of a seperate function
//may need to implement a search based on user input
//if search matches the stored access value, then decode the .txt document
echo $encodedStr; //cannot concat a string by itself, must make into a numeric value
$decodedStr = base64_decode ($encodedStr);
echo nl2br($decodedStr);

?>
```

Is anything unusual about the above code? new to php.

Comment: This code has no part where it must show an upload button (which is what I understand you want), but if you send a Post request an address containing this script it should upload it. Can you re-state the problem for me please?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for uploding a image .

```js
   //javascript
    var image_uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes: 'html5,flash,html4',
        browse_button: "image_uploader",
        container: "image_upload_container",
        url: base_url + 'Blog/upload_files',
        chunk_size: '1mb',
        unique_names: true,
        multi_selection: false,
        resize: {
            width: 300,
            height: 300
        },
        flash_swf_url: base_url + 'assets/js/plupload/js/Moxie.swf',
        silverlight_xap_url: base_url + 'assets/js/plupload/js/Moxie.xap',
        filters: {
            max_file_size: '10mb',
            mime_types: [
                {title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,jpeg,png,pdf"}
            ]
        },
        init: {
            FilesAdded: function (up, files) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    up.start();
                }, 1);
            },
            FileUploaded: function (up, file) {
                $("#image_div").html('<div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-offset-3 text-right">\n\
     <a href="javascript:;" onclick="remove_photo2()">\n\
<i class="fa fa-2x fa-times-circle"></i></a>\n\
<div class="form-group text-left"><input type="hidden" name="image" value="' + file.target_name + '">\n\
<img alt="" class="img img-responsive" src="' + base_url + 'uploads/' + file.target_name + '" height="100" width="100"/></div></div>');
                $("#image").val(file.target_name);
            },
        },
        UploadComplete: function () {
//            $('#image_div').unblock();
        },
        Error: function (up, err) {
//            $('#image_div').unblock();
            bootbox.alert(err.message);
        }

    });
    image_uploader.init();
    function remove_photo2(id) {
        $("#image_div").empty();
    }
```

```html
//php file code 
<div class="form-group">
                                <div class="fileinput fileinput-new row mt-3" data-provides="fileinput" >
                                    <div id="image_div">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <?php if (isset($blog_data['blog_image'])) { ?>
                                                <input class="form" type="hidden" name="image" id="image" value="<?php echo isset($blog_data['blog_image']) ? $blog_data['blog_image'] : ''; ?>">
                                                <img src="<?php
                                                if ($blog_data['blog_image'] != '' && file_exists(FCPATH . 'uploads/blog/' . $blog_data['blog_image'])) {

                                                    echo base_url('uploads/blog/' . $blog_data['blog_image']);
                                                } else {

                                                    echo base_url() . '';
                                                }
                                                ?>" height="70px" width="100px"/>
                                                 <?php } ?>
<!--<input class="form" type="hidden" name="image" id="image">-->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            
                            
                            
// controller code
$time_now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                // upload blog image
                $blog_image = $this->input->post('image');
                if ($blog_image != '') {
                    $time = time();
                    if (file_exists(FCPATH . 'uploads/' . $blog_image)) {
                        $destination_path = FCPATH . 'uploads/blog/' . $time . '/';
                        if (!is_dir($destination_path)) {
                            mkdir($destination_path, 0777, TRUE);
                        }
                        if (copy(FCPATH . 'uploads/' . $blog_image, $destination_path . $blog_image)) {
                            unlink(FCPATH . 'uploads/' . $blog_image);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one for uploding a image .

```js
   //javascript
    var image_uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
        runtimes: 'html5,flash,html4',
        browse_button: "image_uploader",
        container: "image_upload_container",
        url: base_url + 'Blog/upload_files',
        chunk_size: '1mb',
        unique_names: true,
        multi_selection: false,
        resize: {
            width: 300,
            height: 300
        },
        flash_swf_url: base_url + 'assets/js/plupload/js/Moxie.swf',
        silverlight_xap_url: base_url + 'assets/js/plupload/js/Moxie.xap',
        filters: {
            max_file_size: '10mb',
            mime_types: [
                {title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,jpeg,png,pdf"}
            ]
        },
        init: {
            FilesAdded: function (up, files) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    up.start();
                }, 1);
            },
            FileUploaded: function (up, file) {
                $("#image_div").html('<div class="form-group col-sm-6 col-md-offset-3 text-right">\n\
     <a href="javascript:;" onclick="remove_photo2()">\n\
<i class="fa fa-2x fa-times-circle"></i></a>\n\
<div class="form-group text-left"><input type="hidden" name="image" value="' + file.target_name + '">\n\
<img alt="" class="img img-responsive" src="' + base_url + 'uploads/' + file.target_name + '" height="100" width="100"/></div></div>');
                $("#image").val(file.target_name);
            },
        },
        UploadComplete: function () {
//            $('#image_div').unblock();
        },
        Error: function (up, err) {
//            $('#image_div').unblock();
            bootbox.alert(err.message);
        }

    });
    image_uploader.init();
    function remove_photo2(id) {
        $("#image_div").empty();
    }
```

```html
//php file code 
<div class="form-group">
                                <div class="fileinput fileinput-new row mt-3" data-provides="fileinput" >
                                    <div id="image_div">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <?php if (isset($blog_data['blog_image'])) { ?>
                                                <input class="form" type="hidden" name="image" id="image" value="<?php echo isset($blog_data['blog_image']) ? $blog_data['blog_image'] : ''; ?>">
                                                <img src="<?php
                                                if ($blog_data['blog_image'] != '' && file_exists(FCPATH . 'uploads/blog/' . $blog_data['blog_image'])) {

                                                    echo base_url('uploads/blog/' . $blog_data['blog_image']);
                                                } else {

                                                    echo base_url() . '';
                                                }
                                                ?>" height="70px" width="100px"/>
                                                 <?php } ?>
<!--<input class="form" type="hidden" name="image" id="image">-->
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div> 
                            </div>
                            
                            
                            
// controller code
$time_now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
                // upload blog image
                $blog_image = $this->input->post('image');
                if ($blog_image != '') {
                    $time = time();
                    if (file_exists(FCPATH . 'uploads/' . $blog_image)) {
                        $destination_path = FCPATH . 'uploads/blog/' . $time . '/';
                        if (!is_dir($destination_path)) {
                            mkdir($destination_path, 0777, TRUE);
                        }
                        if (copy(FCPATH . 'uploads/' . $blog_image, $destination_path . $blog_image)) {
                            unlink(FCPATH . 'uploads/' . $blog_image);
                        }
                    }
                }

            $blogInsertArray = array(
                
                'blog_image' => "$time" . "/" . $blog_image,
            );
```